# Border radius input animation

Tags: css, css-animations, background-image, border, border-radius

I'm looking to create an animated border input similar to the one shown in this Dribbble post: https://dribbble.com/shots/20266537-Login-page.

Currently, I have an idea using a background image, but it doesn't support border radius:

```css
@keyframes bg {
    0% {
      background-size: 0% 3px, 3px 0, 0 3px, 3px 0;
      background-position: 70px -2px, calc(100% + 2px) -1px, 100% 100%,
        -2px 100%;
    }
    20% {
      background-size: 90% 3px, 3px 0, 0 3px, 3px 0;
      background-position: 70px -2px, calc(100% + 2px) -1px, 100% 100% -2px 100%;
    }
    40% { 
      background-size: 90% 3px, 3px calc(100% + 2px), 0 3px, 3px 0;
      background-position: 70px -2px, calc(100% + 2px) -1px,
        calc(100% + 1px) calc(100% + 2px), -2px 100%;
    }
    60% {
      background-size: 90% 3px, 3px calc(100% + 2px), calc(100% + 2px) 3px,
        3px 0;
      background-position: 70px -2px, calc(100% + 2px) -1px,
        calc(100% + 1px) calc(100% + 2px), -2px 100%;
    }
    100% {
      background-size: 100% 3px, 3px calc(100% + 2px), calc(100% + 2px) 3px,
        3px calc(100% + 2px);
      background-position: 0 -2px, calc(100% + 2px) -1px,
        calc(100% + 1px) calc(100% + 2px), -2px 100%;
/*        border: 2px solid #82c0fe; */
    }
}

.box {
    position:relative;
    border-radius:10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 2rem auto;  
    padding: 2em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:   linear-gradient(to right, #5D26C1, #a17fe0, #59C173),
                        linear-gradient(to bottom, #5D26C1, #a17fe0, #59C173),
                        linear-gradient(to right,#5D26C1, #a17fe0, #59C173),
                        linear-gradient(to bottom, #5D26C1, #a17fe0, #59C173);
    animation: bg 2s forwards 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

I would appreciate any assistance or alternative ideas you may have to achieve the desired effect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using an `<svg>`:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
input:focus {
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.focus {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s;
}

input:focus + * .focus {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <svg width=300 height=50 viewBox="0 0 300 50">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(10)">
        <stop offset="5%" stop-color="blue" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="purple" />
      </linearGradient>
      <mask id=border>
        <rect
          x=1
          y=1
          rx=10
          ry=10
          stroke-width=2
          stroke=#ccc
          width=298
          height=48
          fill=none
          pathLength=1
          stroke-dasharray=1
          stroke-dashoffset=-.08
          id=border
        />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect
      x=1
      y=1
      rx=10
      ry=10
      stroke-width=2
      stroke=#ccc
      width=298
      height=48
      fill=none
      mask=url(#border)
    />
    <rect
      x=1
      y=1
      rx=10
      ry=10
      stroke-width=2
      stroke="url(#gradient)"
      width=298
      height=48
      fill=none
      mask=url(#border)
      pathLength=1
      stroke-dasharray=1
      stroke-dashoffset=.92
      class="focus"
    />
  </svg>
```

## Explanation

The `<svg>` should be the same size as the `input`:

```css
input {
  …
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg width=300 height=50 viewBox="0 0 300 50">
  …
</svg>
```

Have the `<svg>` positioned on top of the `<input>`:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

…

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <svg …>
```

Use a stroked `<rect>` for the inactive border state:

```html
<svg …>
  <rect
    x=1
    y=1
    rx=10
    ry=10
    stroke-width=2
    stroke=#ccc
    width=298
    height=48
    fill=none
  />
</svg>
```

Add another rectangle on top for the gradient stroke:

```html
<svg …>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(10)">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="blue" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="purple" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect
    x=1
    y=1
    rx=10
    ry=10
    stroke-width=2
    stroke=#ccc
    width=298
    height=48
    fill=none
  />
  <rect
    x=1
    y=1
    rx=10
    ry=10
    stroke-width=2
    stroke="url(#gradient)"
    width=298
    height=48
    fill=none
  />
</svg>
```

Add a mask to both `<rect>`s for the gap

```html
<svg …>
  <defs>
    …
    <mask id=border>
      <rect
        x=1
        y=1
        rx=10
        ry=10
        stroke-width=2
        stroke=#ccc
        width=298
        height=48
        fill=none
        pathLength=1
        stroke-dasharray=1
        stroke-dashoffset=-.08
        id=border
      />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect
    …
    mask=url(#border)
  />
  <rect
    …
    mask=url(#border)
    pathLength=1
  />
</svg>
```

Add the stroke animation on focus by having a stroke length with dashes, where the dash is the length of the `<rect>`. Have the gap of the dash be displayed and then transition it such that the "filled-in" portion of the stroke dash becomes visible.

```css
.focus {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s;
}

input:focus + * .focus {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg …>
  …
  <rect
    …
    pathLength=1
    stroke-dasharray=1
    stroke-dashoffset=.92
    class="focus"
  />
</svg>
```